# Как занести информацию в базу?

Tags: база-данных, php

Есть таблица, которая состоит из трёх полей: `id, view, position.`
На странице циклом выводятся блоки с инпутами, указанными в таблице.
Записей - 15. И форма для всех этих блоков и кнопка СОХРАНИТЬ одна.
Как сохранить все изменения для всех записей в базу?
Не могу сообразить, так как для каждого блока будут инпуты с
одинаковыми именами переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одну форму просто одинаковые имена ставить неосмысленно, работать не будет (`php` их по уникальным ключам возьмет), можно специальным образом массив объявить `name="a[]"`) тогда `php` из каждого такого одинакового имени сделает массив, но нужно следить, чтобы не было пропусков, иначе не найдете к какой строке принадлежит значение.

Comment: Не совсем понял про массив. Как это реализовать?

Comment: в форме

    <input type="text" name="id[]">

в php будет массив 

    $_POST['id'][0...]

Comment: А, понятно. Спасибо.